# load the data list from the file into a map in groovy split by colon

Tags: groovy

I have a below list and I want to load the data into a map in Groovy using split method to separate the key-value pairs and then iterate them to populate the map.

**myfile.txt**

```
name:john
name2:peter
name3:albert
```

**expected result:**

```
[name: 'john', name2: 'peter', name3: 'albert']
```

**My code is - "map_users.groovy":**

```
  def readFile = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat myfile.txt").trim()
     def map = [:]
        readFile.eachLine {line ->
           def(key,value) = line.split(':')
               map[key.trim()] : value.toString()
                   }
            println map
```

Comment: Does `def map = readFile("myfile.txt").readLines().collectEntries { it.split(':', 2) }` work?

Comment: Replace the `:` with `=` and/or add the error/problem

Comment: i have this error:  

"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Entry for class: java.util.Map"

Comment: `map[...] : value...` is wrong; use a `=` here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `=` when assigning the value to the map. So, instead of `map[key.trim()] : value.toString()` it should be: `map[key.trim()] = value.toString()`. Here is the working code:

```
def map = [:]
readFile.eachLine { line ->
    def (key, value) = line.split(':')
    map[key.trim()] = value.toString()
}
println map
```

If your file is not too big, you may also consider to use `collectEntries` to transform lines into map:

```
def map = readFile.readLines().collectEntries {line ->
    def (key, value) = line.split(':')
    [(key.trim()) : value.toString()]
}
println map
```

Comment: `collectEntries` also works with a "tuple", which makes it more readable: `[key.trim(), value.toString()]`

Comment: Also, this will fail if a line is `key:value:with:colon`